Unable to access the devtools of my Microsoft Teams app from Microsoft Teams Android app
I need to debug one issue in my app running in Microsoft Teams android client. I have a configurable tab and the tab is not loading sometimes and throwing some error. Hence, I need to check the inspect or the console tab in devtools when my app is running in the Microsoft Teams android client.
I have followed the instructions provided on the following guide but unable to view the console of the running app inside android app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools#access-devtools-from-an-android-device
After enabling Developer Preview in tenant settings, updating the android app to beta version and enabling USB Debugging in my android device, if I connect my android to laptop using USB and go to chrome://inspect/#devices I am only seeing my device name but nothing for the tab that I have open in the Microsoft Teams android app.


If you are still facing this issue, please share your version number.

I was able to connect to DevTools for an app I'm developing.
Can you try checking the following?

Verify that you're on the Beta Version of the app, name of the App would be "Microsoft Teams (Beta)" from previous "Microsoft Teams". The Beta Test Profile takes 5-10 mins to sync, post that I was able to see an option to upgrade to the Beta Version on Play Store.

Enable "Developer Preview" in Teams App in "Settings -> About" section of the app.




